# Why Casperjs can only load half page of Outlook.com? Images included

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

is there any one know what kind of problem is that?

should i add any path to support casperjs?

any solution to make it displayable?

thanks for your help.

[Click here for picture: First picture is using casperjs, which cant load like a regular browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iFu7.jpg)

Comment: you can click in the blue sentence and it will bring you to the picture, thanks

Comment: You forgot to include your code sample. Also, be sure to mention your CasperJS and PhantomJS versions.

Comment: hi vaviloff, sorry for not enough info of this question. it is because this script included some login info. But now i have added a new question and included everything, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703691/why-casperjs-cant-show-part-of-a-web-site-outlook-com and give me some advice! thanks