# Why can't CasperJS show part of a web site 'outlook.com'?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have problem of capturing everything of a web page. After I log in to outlook.com using regular browser, it should show the inbox message in the right side:

[image: Click here for comparison picture]

However, when I use CasperJS, it is just blank. Does anyone have any idea?

I have include a temporary login id in the script, you can test it if you can, thanks.

Here is the script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "info",
  viewportSize: {width: 1280,height: 720},
  pageSettings: {userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"}
});

casper.start('http://www.hotmail.com').then(function () {
  console.log('got here');
});

casper.wait(500, function () {
  console.log('wait');
});

casper.then(function(){
  this.sendKeys("[name='loginfmt']", 'peterwhite12345678@outlook.com');
  this.sendKeys("[name='passwd']", '12345678peterwhite');
  this.click("[type='submit']");
  console.log('entering log in information');
  });

casper.wait(5000, function () {
  console.log('wait');
});

casper.then(function (){
    console.log('printscreen');
    casper.capture('there_is_nothing_by_the_right_side.png')
});

casper.run();
```

I have also tried something like

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=any outlook.js
```

Should I maybe add any path/plugin to support this CasperJS?

Comment: and i am using casperjs version 1.1.0-beta4 using phantomjs version 1.9.8

Comment: Your script looks fine. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Why are you repeatedly asking same question when you have already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670589/why-casperjs-can-only-load-half-page-of-outlook-com-images-included)

Comment: hi prateek naik, i am repeatedly asking the same question because I didnt put my script on the first one, so i re-organize it and make a new one, sorry for bothering. any advice for my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code. You need to give/provide enough time to open web page

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
// verbose: true,
// logLevel: "info",
viewportSize: {width: 1280, height: 720},
pageSettings: {userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"}
});

casper.start('http://www.hotmail.com').then(function () {
    console.log('got here');
});

casper.wait(1000, function () {
    console.log('wait');
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.sendKeys("[name='loginfmt']", 'peterwhite12345678@outlook.com');
    this.sendKeys("[name='passwd']", '12345678peterwhite');
    this.click("[type='submit']");
    console.log('entering log in information');
});

casper.wait(20000, function () {
    this.waitForSelector('#O365_MainLink_Settings', function () {
        this.test.assertExists('#O365_Lync_ButtonID', 'Lync icon is visble, hence confirmed that page opened completely');
    });
});

casper.waitForSelector(('._rp_52 > div:nth-child(4)'), function () {
    if (this.visible("button._rp_o1:nth-child(2)")) {
        console.log("Here we go, Right side is visible");
        casper.capture('there is something.png');
    }
    else {
        console.log("Nope")
    }

});

casper.run();
```

Comment: hi prateek, thanks for your help i am really appreciate! However, i am still not able to display the right side. here is what i try:

Comment: hi prateek, thanks for your help i am really appreciate! However, i am still not able to display the right side. I put a "console log" after "this.test.assertExists", but that console log is just not showing.... and the last reply from terminal is "entering log in information"....; also, if i remove "this.waitForSelector & this.test.assertExist"...and run casper.waitForSelector directly after waiting 20000, the reply from terminal is timeout...

Comment: .The thing I am concerning right now is the version of my casperjs...It is because I tried phantomjs 1.9.8, the right side is not visible....but it is visible if i use phantomjs  2.1.1(However I dont know why the phantom is crashed after several try which make me quite disappointed!! )..............so which version of casperjs are you using? I am on casperjs1.1.0-beta4.. thanks

Comment: @Robert Choy, Currently i am using PhantomJS 1.9.7 version and Casperjs 1.1.0-beta5. Just try with lower version of phantomJS. But i got entire page after providing wait()

Comment: thanks prateek, i have tried waiting 50,000 but it seems not ok! so i think the version of phantomjs or casperjs does matter! thanks for your help it is very important for me!

Comment: hello again! i tried so many times after figuring the differences between different version of phantomjs/casperjs. and what i am using is exactly as same as your setting, but it is still not working. However, there might have some extra setting may help. When my first try using 1.9.7, it won't load hotmail.com because it is a https site, so i added --ssl-protocol=any, and it works for the log in part, but the right side is still invisible. so, i want to give one last try, is there anything like "--ssl-protocol" I am missing? ...and do you think your outlook page is visible everytime? thanks!!!